# Quick code editing feature

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS2015 on-premise the feature of editing files from web interface can be disabled?

It seems that this feature doesn't consider the check-in policies.

Comment: Funny enough, when googling this I've found your comment to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2015/03/18/add-edit-rename-and-delete-files-in-the-web-browser-with-visual-studio-online-and-tfs-2015.aspx), and a guy from Microsoft confirmed checkin policies will be skipped. BTW, branch policies for Git still work in this scenario. I failed to find a way to disable "web edit" feature, and I doubt it can be done...

Comment: Yes, I've tried my luck in MSDN forums; they confirmed that's no way to disable it which I found very annoying.

Comment: Submitted to user voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9699246-quick-code-editing-switch-or-warning

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around this by installing the IIS [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and adding a rewrite rule that returns a `403` to `POSTs` to the api method called by Quick Edit:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="PreventQuickEditCheckin" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="*" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{URL}" pattern="/tfs/collection/_apis/tfvc/changesets" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="POST" />
         <add input="{HEADER_X-Requested-With}" pattern="XMLHttpRequest" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="CustomResponse" 
             statusCode="403" 
             statusReason="Forbidden: This action is not permitted." 
             statusDescription="Quick edit is currently disabled to prevent
                                checkin policies being circumvented." />
   </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

The additional constraint of only doing this for requests with the `X-Requested-With` header (added by jQuery) is to ensure this method is only blocked by requests from TFS Web.

Whilst I have not seen this have any impact on other aspects of TFS functionality, I make no guarantees that this could have unexpected or undesired results!